# How to split a column into multiple columns with the index of the string with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame, it looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["sea001", "seac002"]})
print(df)

         a
0   sea001
1  seac002
```

I want to split the a column into two columns, the first three characters in column "b", the rest in column "c"

```
         a    b     c
0   sea001  sea   001
1  seac002  sea  c002
```

I want to use df.a.str.split(), but there is no option for me to separate the words after the index. How can I do this cleverly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str` with slicing semantics to do this:

```
In [102]:
df['b'], df['c'] = df['a'].str[:3], df['a'].str[3:]
df

Out[102]:
         a    b     c
0   sea001  sea   001
1  seac002  sea  c002
```

Answer (score 1):

try [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [104]: df[['b','c']] = df.a.str.extract(r'(.{3})(.*)', expand=True)

In [105]: df
Out[105]:
         a    b     c
0   sea001  sea   001
1  seac002  sea  c002
```